# How to Save UITabBarController tabs orders

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller, exit

I have a customized `UITabBarController` ˚ where users can re-order the tabs as I have more than 5 tabs, the question is how I can save the re-ordered tabs after exiting the application?

Answer (score 0):

Define an enumeration type for the tabs.
Create an array that holds the current order of the tabs using the enumeration type.
Whenever the user reorders the tabs, update the array and serialize it.
On app launch reconstruct the tab order from the deserialized array.

Comment: thanks Volker, forgive me as I'm newbie, can u share an example plz